# Rescale data frame columns as percentages of baseline entry with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I often need to rescale time series relative to their value at a certain baseline time (usually as a percent of the baseline). Here's an example.

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(magrittr)
> library(tibble)
> library(tidyr)
# [messages from package imports snipped]
> set.seed(42)
> mexico <- tibble(Year=2000:2004, Country='Mexico', A=10:14+rnorm(5), B=20:24+rnorm(5))
> usa <- tibble(Year=2000:2004, Country='USA', A=30:34+rnorm(5), B=40:44+rnorm(5))
> table <- rbind(mexico, usa)
> table
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    Year Country     A     B
   <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2000 Mexico   11.4  19.9
 2  2001 Mexico   10.4  22.5
 3  2002 Mexico   12.4  21.9
 4  2003 Mexico   13.6  25.0
 5  2004 Mexico   14.4  23.9
 6  2000 USA      31.3  40.6
 7  2001 USA      33.3  40.7
 8  2002 USA      30.6  39.3
 9  2003 USA      32.7  40.6
10  2004 USA      33.9  45.3
```

I want to scale `A` and `B` to express each value as a percent of the country-specific 2001 value (i.e., the `A` and `B` entries in rows `2` and `7` should be `100`). My way of doing this is somewhat roundabout and awkward: extract the baseline values into a separate table, merge them back into a separate column in the main table, and then compute scaled values, with annoying intermediate gathering and spreading to avoid specifying the column names of each time series (real data sets can have far more than two value columns). Is there a better way to do this, ideally with a single short pipeline?

```
> long_table <- table %>% gather(variable, value, -Year, -Country)
> long_table
# A tibble: 20 x 4
    Year Country variable value
   <int> <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
 1  2000 Mexico  A         11.4
 2  2001 Mexico  A         10.4
#[remaining tibble printout snipped]
> baseline_table <- long_table %>%
    filter(Year == 2001) %>%
    select(-Year) %>%
    rename(baseline=value)
> baseline_table
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Country variable baseline
  <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>
1 Mexico  A            10.4
2 USA     A            33.3
3 Mexico  B            22.5
4 USA     B            40.7
> normalized_table <- long_table %>%
  inner_join(baseline_table) %>% 
  mutate(value=100*value/baseline) %>%
  select(-baseline) %>%
  spread(variable, value) %>%
  arrange(Country, Year)
Joining, by = c("Country", "variable")
> normalized_table
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    Year Country     A     B
   <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2000 Mexico  109.   88.4
 2  2001 Mexico  100.  100
 3  2002 Mexico  118.   97.3
 4  2003 Mexico  131.  111.
 5  2004 Mexico  138.  106.
 6  2000 USA      94.0  99.8
 7  2001 USA     100   100
 8  2002 USA      92.0  96.6
 9  2003 USA      98.3  99.6
10  2004 USA     102.  111.
```

My second attempt was to use `transform`, but this failed because `transform` doesn't seem to recognize `dplyr` groups, and it would be suboptimal even if it worked because it requires me to know that 2001 is the second year in the time series.

```
> table %>%
  arrange(Country, Year) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -Year, -Country) %>%
  group_by(Country, variable) %>%
  transform(norm=value*100/value[2])
   Year Country variable    value     norm
1  2000  Mexico        A 11.37096 108.9663
2  2001  Mexico        A 10.43530 100.0000
3  2002  Mexico        A 12.36313 118.4741
4  2003  Mexico        A 13.63286 130.6418
5  2004  Mexico        A 14.40427 138.0340
6  2000     USA        A 31.30487 299.9901
7  2001     USA        A 33.28665 318.9811
8  2002     USA        A 30.61114 293.3422
9  2003     USA        A 32.72121 313.5627
10 2004     USA        A 33.86668 324.5395
11 2000  Mexico        B 19.89388 190.6402
12 2001  Mexico        B 22.51152 215.7247
13 2002  Mexico        B 21.90534 209.9157
14 2003  Mexico        B 25.01842 239.7480
15 2004  Mexico        B 23.93729 229.3876
16 2000     USA        B 40.63595 389.4085
17 2001     USA        B 40.71575 390.1732
18 2002     USA        B 39.34354 377.0235
19 2003     USA        B 40.55953 388.6762
20 2004     USA        B 45.32011 434.2961
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Camille's answer, I found one simple approach that that scales well:

```
table %>%
  gather(variable, value, -Year, -Country) %>%
  group_by(Country, variable) %>%
  mutate(value=100*value/value[Year == 2001]) %>%
  spread(variable, value)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   Country [2]
    Year Country     A     B
   <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2000 Mexico  109.   88.4
 2  2000 USA      94.0  99.8
 3  2001 Mexico  100.  100
 4  2001 USA     100   100
 5  2002 Mexico  118.   97.3
 6  2002 USA      92.0  96.6
 7  2003 Mexico  131.  111.
 8  2003 USA      98.3  99.6
 9  2004 Mexico  138.  106.
10  2004 USA     102.  111.
```

Preserving the the original values alongside the scaled ones takes more work. Here are two approaches. One of them uses an extra `gather` call to produce two variable-name columns (one indicating the series name, the other marking `original` or `scaled`), then unifying them into one column and reformatting.

```
table %>%
  gather(variable, original, -Year, -Country) %>%
  group_by(Country, variable) %>%
  mutate(scaled=100*original/original[Year == 2001]) %>%
  gather(scaled, value, -Year, -Country, -variable) %>% 
  unite(variable_scaled, variable, scaled, sep='_') %>% 
  mutate(variable_scaled=gsub("_original", "", variable_scaled)) %>% 
  spread(variable_scaled, value)
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   Country [2]
    Year Country     A A_scaled     B B_scaled
   <int> <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  2000 Mexico   11.4    109.   19.9     88.4
 2  2000 USA      31.3     94.0  40.6     99.8
 3  2001 Mexico   10.4    100.   22.5    100
 4  2001 USA      33.3    100    40.7    100
 5  2002 Mexico   12.4    118.   21.9     97.3
 6  2002 USA      30.6     92.0  39.3     96.6
 7  2003 Mexico   13.6    131.   25.0    111.
 8  2003 USA      32.7     98.3  40.6     99.6
 9  2004 Mexico   14.4    138.   23.9    106.
10  2004 USA      33.9    102.   45.3    111.
```

A second equivalent approach creates a new table with the columns scaled "in place" and then merges it back into with the original one.

```
table %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -Year, -Country) %>%
  group_by(Country, variable) %>%
  mutate(value=100*value/value[Year == 2001]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(variable=paste(variable, 'scaled', sep='_')) %>% 
  spread(variable, value) %>%
  inner_join(table)
Joining, by = c("Year", "Country")
# A tibble: 10 x 6
    Year Country A_scaled B_scaled     A     B
   <int> <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2000 Mexico     109.      88.4  11.4  19.9
 2  2000 USA         94.0     99.8  31.3  40.6
 3  2001 Mexico     100.     100    10.4  22.5
 4  2001 USA        100      100    33.3  40.7
 5  2002 Mexico     118.      97.3  12.4  21.9
 6  2002 USA         92.0     96.6  30.6  39.3
 7  2003 Mexico     131.     111.   13.6  25.0
 8  2003 USA         98.3     99.6  32.7  40.6
 9  2004 Mexico     138.     106.   14.4  23.9
10  2004 USA        102.     111.   33.9  45.3
```

It's possible to replace the final `inner_join` with `arrange(County, Year) %>% select(-Country, -Year) %>% bind_cols(table)`, which may perform better for some data sets, though it orders the columns suboptimally.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice for this to be more scalable, but here's a simple solution. You can refer to `A[Year == 2001]` inside `mutate`, much as you might do `table$A[table$Year == 2001]` in base R. This lets you scale against your baseline of 2001 or whatever other year you might need.

**Edit:** I was missing a `group_by` to ensure that values are only being scaled against other values in their own group. The "sanity check" (that I clearly didn't do) is that values for Mexico in 2001 should have a scaled value of 1, and same for USA and any other countries.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
mexico <- tibble(Year=2000:2004, Country='Mexico', A=10:14+rnorm(5), B=20:24+rnorm(5))
usa <- tibble(Year=2000:2004, Country='USA', A=30:34+rnorm(5), B=40:44+rnorm(5))
table <- rbind(mexico, usa)

table %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(A_base2001 = A / A[Year == 2001], B_base2001 = B / B[Year == 2001])
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#> # Groups:   Country [2]
#>     Year Country     A     B A_base2001 B_base2001
#>    <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1  2000 Mexico   11.4  19.9      1.09       0.884
#>  2  2001 Mexico   10.4  22.5      1          1    
#>  3  2002 Mexico   12.4  21.9      1.18       0.973
#>  4  2003 Mexico   13.6  25.0      1.31       1.11 
#>  5  2004 Mexico   14.4  23.9      1.38       1.06 
#>  6  2000 USA      31.3  40.6      0.940      0.998
#>  7  2001 USA      33.3  40.7      1          1    
#>  8  2002 USA      30.6  39.3      0.920      0.966
#>  9  2003 USA      32.7  40.6      0.983      0.996
#> 10  2004 USA      33.9  45.3      1.02       1.11
```

Created on 2018-05-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Shouldn't the `2001` entries under `A_base2001` and `B_base2001` both be `1`? I think the problem is that the length-two vectors of baselines (e.g. `c(10.4, 33.3)` for `A`) are being recycled against `A` in its given order: Mexico 2000 against the Mexico baseline, then Mexico 2001 against the USA baseline, then again Mexico 2002 against the Mexico baseline, and so forth. Adding an `arrange(year)` fixes this by aligning pairs of year entries, but then it's also fragile if any year/country combinations are missing (a common occurrence in actual data).

Comment: Honestly, is this a common enough problem that it would be worth writing a `dplyr` extension package to solve?

Comment: @ConnorHarris yes, I don't know how I missed that! Adding a `group_by` fixes it, so Mexico values are only being scaled against one another, and same for USA. I'm fixing that now.

Comment: @ConnorHarris at least in my line of work, which is analyzing demographic and other Census data, it is a very common task that usually takes me a lot of `gather`/`spread` wrangling. I'm actually writing a package right now for work with a function to streamline and scale this process

Comment: I think I found a working approach that doesn't require specifying column names.